# How to solve 404 eero in traefik. subdomain shows 404 but exposing port works fine

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik, portainer

I am deploying portainer and traefik in a docker swarm environment. I can be able to hit traefik dashboard with domain `traefik.example.com`. I want also to proxy to portainer container but when I hit `portainer.example.com` I get a 404 error. The logs in traefik are not showing anything about hitting that url

```
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[traefik.frontend.rule:Host(`traefik.shmmir.ml`) traefik.port:8080]]"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[com.docker.stack.image:traefik:v1.7.16 com.docker.stack.namespace:proxy traefik.frontend.rule:Host(`traefik.shmmir.ml`) traefik.port:8080]"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[traefik.frontend.rule:Host(`traefik.shmmir.ml`) traefik.port:8080]]"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[com.docker.stack.image:portainer/portainer com.docker.stack.namespace:portainer traefik.enable:true traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints:http traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule:Host(`portainer.shmmir.ml`) traefik.http.routers.portainer.service:portainer traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port:9000]"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[traefik.enable:true traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints:http traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule:Host(`portainer.shmmir.ml`) traefik.http.routers.portainer.service:portainer] http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server:map[traefik.port:9000]]"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="Backend backend-portainer-web-http-services-portainer-loadbalancer-server: no load-balancer defined, fallback to 'wrr' method"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="Backend backend-proxy-traefik: no load-balancer defined, fallback to 'wrr' method"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"backends\":{\"backend-portainer-web-http-services-portainer-loadbalancer-server\":{\"servers\":{\"server-portainer-web-1-d30efeb58bae18c84b91c7662dd19a7a\":{\"url\":\"http://10.0.98.159:9000\",\"weight\":1}},\"loadBalancer\":{\"method\":\"wrr\"}},\"backend-proxy-traefik\":{\"servers\":{\"server-proxy-traefik-f5zxe8dngv29a259b42l1tu78-e19913f7535b25062e55b9f66b4c375b\":{\"url\":\"http://10.0.98.4:8080\",\"weight\":1},\"server-proxy-traefik-rm54k6hi3dbmzfl7udi83xhej-cb81f0e3dbaa25243ab90850c80dc1a5\":{\"url\":\"http://10.0.98.3:8080\",\"weight\":1}},\"loadBalancer\":{\"method\":\"wrr\"}}},\"frontends\":{\"frontend-Host-traefik-shmmir-ml-0\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"http\",\"https\"],\"backend\":\"backend-proxy-traefik\",\"routes\":{\"route-frontend-Host-traefik-shmmir-ml-0\":{\"rule\":\"Host(`traefik.shmmir.ml`)\"}},\"passHostHeader\":true,\"priority\":0,\"basicAuth\":null},\"frontend-http-services-portainer-loadbalancer-server-portainer-web-http-services-portainer-loadbalancer-server\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"http\",\"https\"],\"backend\":\"backend-portainer-web-http-services-portainer-loadbalancer-server\",\"routes\":{\"route-frontend-http-services-portainer-loadbalancer-server-portainer-web-http-services-portainer-loadbalancer-server\":{\"rule\":\"Host:portainer-web.traefik\"}},\"passHostHeader\":true,\"priority\":0,\"basicAuth\":null}}}"
proxy_traefik.0.f5zxe8dngv29@dvc2    | time="2020-05-22T13:45:40Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker"
```

But when I expose portainer using port number 9000 and hit `example.com:9000` I can get it's UI. So this means that maybe my rules are not working or something. Here are the labels I've used in portainer service

```
      labels:
        - 'traefik.enable=true'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=http'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.${DOMAIN}`)'
        # - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer_.entryPoints=websecure'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.service=portainer'
        - 'traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000'
```

and labels for the traefik service

```
 labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.port=8080
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host(`traefik.${DOMAIN}`) #traefik.${DOMAIN}
```

I've put them on the same network,
`traefik service`

```
    networks:
      - proxy
      - traefik-consul
      - traefik-docker
```

`portainer service`

```
    networks:
      - proxy
      - portainer
```

PS: Traefik is using this image `image: traefik:v1.7.16`

I really don't get it..